# How do I convert the methods and constructers from this UML to real code?

Tags: java

I'm trying to convert a uml sheet into real code. I have already done the parameters, getters and setters. But I'm having some difficulties with the methods and constructors.

This is what the UML of this class looks like:

[image: UML Diagram Shape Class]

(the names are in Dutch sorry about that)

This is what I have wrote so far:

```
public class Shape {

private int shapeTeller;

protected String kleur;

protected Boolean gevuld;

public int getShapeTeller() {
    return shapeTeller;
}


public void setShapeTeller(int shapeTeller) {
    this.shapeTeller = shapeTeller;
}


public String getKleur() {
    return kleur;
}


public void setKleur(String kleur) {
    this.kleur = kleur;
}


public Boolean getGevuld() {
    return gevuld;
}


public void setGevuld(Boolean gevuld) {
    this.gevuld = gevuld;
}


public Shape() {

}
}
```

Could anyone help me write the rest of the code?

Comment: What's left, the constructors? Please be specific about what you're asking for.

Comment: I've never heard of ULM. I think you're talking about UML (Unified Modeling Language). I've edited the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the constructor your missing:

```
public Shape(final String kleur, final boolean gevuld) {
    this.kleur = kleur;
    this.gevuld = gevuld;
}
```

Here are methods declarations (i don't know what they should do):

```
public double getOmtrek() {
    double omtrek = ... //doStuff to get omtrek
    return omtrek;
}

public double getOppervlakte() {
    double oppervlakte = ... //doStuff to get oppervlakte 
    return oppervlakte;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    //for example:
    return "This shape has kleur: " + kleur + " and gevuld is " + gevuld;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are just left with the constructor part. It all depends on what you want to do when a particular constructor is called:

```
public Shape() {
        // do something
        // assign some default values
        this.kleur = "white";
        this.gevuld = false;
}

public Shape(String kleur, Boolean gevuld){
    this.kleur = kleur;
    this.gevuld = gevuld;
}
```